# Use DI tool unity to create EF ObjectContext object

Tags: entity-framework-4, unity-container, objectcontext

I tried to register type in container using script below, it works well

```
 Container.RegisterType<System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext,
              ExSS.Repository.MyEntity>( "myentity", new InjectionConstructor());
```

however, when i try to  use xml config:

```
<alias alias="ObjectContext" 
        type="System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext,System.Data.Entity" />
<alias alias="MyEntity" type="ExSS.Repository.MyEntity,ExSS.Repository"/>
<register type="ExSS.Repository.MyEntity,ExSS.Repository" mapTo="MyEntity" 
        name="myentity">
    <constructor></constructor>
</register>
```

It does not work. The error message is:

```
The type name or alias ObjectContext could not be resolved. Please check your 
configuration file and verify this type name.
```

Description:

```
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error 
and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias ObjectContext could 
not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
```

The stack trace is:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias ObjectContext could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolverImpl.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias, Boolean throwIfResolveFails) +200
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolver.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias) +59
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.GetRegisteringType() +70
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) +111
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerConfiguringElement.ConfigureContainerInternal(IUnityContainer container) +39
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ConfigureContainer>b__0(ContainerConfiguringElement element) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach(IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action) +200
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) +269
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(IUnityContainer container, String configuredContainerName) +133
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer container, UnityConfigurationSection section, String containerName) +70
```

could anyone give some suggections? thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason, it is related to that assembly System.Data.Entity could not be loaded by CLR correctly. publicktokenkey and culture and version should be added. Config below works:

```
<alias alias="ObjectContext" type="System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
<alias alias="MyEntity" type="ExSS.Repository.MyEntity, ExSS.Repository"/> 
<register type="ObjectContext" mapTo="MyEntity" name="myentity"> 
  <constructor /> 
</register>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is wrong. It should be:

```
<alias alias="ObjectContext" type="System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity" />
<alias alias="MyEntity" type="ExSS.Repository.MyEntity, ExSS.Repository"/>
<register type="ObjectContext" mapTo="MyEntity" name="myentity">
    <constructor />
</register>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified config as above, got the same error message as before.  seems Object could not be registered from xml, I register it in code first

Comment: : _container.RegisterType<System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, ExSS.Repository.MyEntity>("myentity",new InjectionConstructor()); 

and config other classes in xml, some of these classes have field which depend on System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, in xml it is like:
    <container name="ExssUnityCfg">
      <register type="IRepositoryFactory" mapTo="RepositoryFactory">
        <constructor>
          <param name ="context" type="ObjectContext">
            <dependency name="myentity"  type="ObjectContext" />
          </param>
        </constructor>
 </container>

Comment: but sadly, i got the same error message. seems that container ExssUnityCfg cannot resolve ObjectContext defined in the code